# Is it possible to upgrade your companion's primary/default weapon?

Tags: fallout-4

I enjoy having Nick Valentine as my companion, but his pipe revolver pistol looks like crap. I have quite a bit of resources, is it possible for me to get his pipe pistol and upgrade it?

I know I can give him other modded weapons, but he has infinite ammo for his revolver, so that's what I want to focus on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the vanilla game, no, you are not able to replace or modify a companion's default weapon. There are multiple discussions about this online, like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3v6k3l/can_you_upgrade_follower_weapons/):

> There's no way to get their default weapon. Even if you equip another one on them their default one never appears in the inventory.

[Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72910348) is another:

> No you cant upgrade the default one. Yes you can give them a better one. Put a weapon in their inventorwand press triangle on their side of the screen to equip it. For guns they need ammo though.

---

However, if you are on PC, there *are* mods to change this behavior, however, such as [this one](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/13519/?).

Comment: That mod is available on PS4 and Xbox as well, through Bethesda's website.